# How to vectorize this for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix

I have a numpy array **f** with length *n* and a numpy matrix **A** with size *n* x *m*. I want to break **f** and **A** in *r* pieces **f1**,...,**fr** and **A1**,...,**Ar**, then make the computations **fi*Ai** (the vector x matrix multiplication in the mathematical sense) with each **fi** being a row vector with the number of columns equal the number of rows of **Ai**. The result will be a row vector 1 x *m*. The idea is to concatenate all these row vectors to form the matrix **B = [ [f1*A1], [f2*A2],..., [fr*Ar] ]** (note that this will be a matrix with size *r* x *m*).

Suppose **f** and **A** are already defined. Also suppose the corresponding index of the pieces are in a list **[0,d1,...dr]**. For example, **f1 = f[d[0]:d[1]]** and **f2 = f[d[1]:d[2]]** ). I was using with the following piece of code to solve my problem:

```
B = numpy.zeros([r,m])
for i in range(0,r):
    lower = d[i]
    upper = d[i+1]
    B[i,:] = f[lower:upper].dot(A[lower:upper,:])
```

The problem is that this piece of code will be computed several times in my program. I heard before that Python for loops are slow and in fact the bottle neck of my code is this part. I can't figure out how to vectorize this but I feel it is possible. I was hoping someone here could show me the way. Thanks.

Comment: If i start at 0, then `B[i-1,:]` will give you a negative index

Comment: Can you provide test data ?

Comment: But you should be able to do something like: `index = np.column_stack((d[:-1],d[1:]))` and then `B = f[index].dot(A[index,:])`

Comment: @obchardon sorry, it was supposed to be i, not i-1.

Comment: Give ius [mcve].  A good answer will use a concrete example, with real numbers.  This is for clarity, and proof that the answer is correct.  I prefer to use an example provided by you, rather than make one up myself.  It's easier, and requires fewer assumptions.

Comment: @hpaulj I didn't know about MCVE, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a valid MCVE:

```
In [139]: f = np.arange(10)
In [140]: A = np.arange(20).reshape(10,2)
In [141]: f.dot(A)
Out[141]: array([570, 615])
In [142]: d = [0,2,5,10]
In [143]: for i,j in zip(d[:-1],d[1:]):
     ...:     print(f[i:j].dot(A[i:j,:]))
     ...:     
[2 3]
[58 67]
[510 545]
```

where `570` = `2+58+510`.

```
In [145]: np.array([f[i:j].dot(A[i:j,:]) for i,j in zip(d[:-1],d[1:])])
Out[145]: 
array([[  2,   3],
       [ 58,  67],
       [510, 545]])
```

Given that the `i:j` slices can vary in length, it may be hard to 'vectorize' this in the true sense.  We can hide the iterations, but writing it in a way that moves all iterations into compiled code will be tricky.  Accumulative operations like `cumsum` are often the best bet.  We often have to step back and look at the problem from a different perspective (as opposed to simply removing the loop).

`numba` and `cython` are often used to speed up iterative solutions, but I won't get into those.

---

If `d` divides the arrays into equal parts, we can use reshaping to calculate the pieces:

```
In [228]: A.shape
Out[228]: (10, 2)
In [229]: f.shape
Out[229]: (10,)
In [230]: f2 = f.reshape(2,5)
In [231]: A2 = A.reshape(2,5,2)

In [233]: np.einsum('ij,ijk->ik',f2,A2)
Out[233]: 
array([[ 60,  70],
       [510, 545]])
```

The `matmul` operator also  works, though it requires some fiddling with the dimensions:

```
In [236]: (f2[:,None,:]@A2)[:,0,:]
Out[236]: 
array([[ 60,  70],
       [510, 545]])
```

---

If `d` divides the arrays into just a couple of sizes, I imagine we could group common sizes, and perform the above reshape and einsum on each group, but I haven't worked out the details:

```
In [238]: d = [0,2,5,7,10]
In [239]: np.array([f[i:j].dot(A[i:j,:]) for i,j in zip(d[:-1],d[1:])])
Out[239]: 
array([[  2,   3],
       [ 58,  67],
       [122, 133],
       [388, 412]])
In [240]: [f[i:j] for i,j in zip(d[:-1],d[1:])]
Out[240]: [array([0, 1]), array([2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])]
```

Here we have 2 groups, one of length 2 and other length 3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can only read it in a few hours. But I will read and give a feedback.

Comment: I could read your answer now, but probably in a few minutes I'll have to leave the computer (for a few hours). You said it may be hard to vectorize the loop because the slices i:j can vary in length. What if I have slices of same length? Is it possible to vectorize somehow? Because my original problem has only two possible sizes for the slices.

Comment: You think I can have more speed up with numba or cython?

Comment: If the slices all have the same length, then we can probably reshape the arrays, and take the dot product with one call (possibly with `einsum`).  If there are just a few lengths, we could do the same, but with groups of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.add.reduceat`:

```
# example data
>>> f = np.arange(10)
>>> A = np.arange(50).reshape(10, 5)
>>> split = [0, 3, 5, 10]
>>> 
# reduceat
>>> np.add.reduceat(f[:, None] * A, split[:-1], axis=0)
array([[  25,   28,   31,   34,   37],
       [ 125,  132,  139,  146,  153],
       [1275, 1310, 1345, 1380, 1415]])
>>> 
# double check against list comprehension
>>> [fi @ Ai for fi, Ai in zip(*map(np.split, (f, A), 2*(split[1:-1],)))]
[array([25, 28, 31, 34, 37]), array([125, 132, 139, 146, 153]), array([1275, 1310, 1345, 1380, 1415])]
```

I wouldn't be surprised if the list comprehension or @hpaulj's solution or OP's loop were faster because of `blas` accelerated matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can only read it in a few hours. But I will read and give a feedback.

Comment: I think list comprehension is the winner